# How to use becomes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Post` Class and a `Comment` Class. I have a post object and want to convert it to a Comment object. I went through Rails api and found becomes(klass).For now there is not association between a Post and Comment. So i tried

```
@post.becomes(Comment)
```

but becomes method could not be found for `@post` object. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about classes deriving from ActiveRecord::Base. In that case, I think you have two options if you really want to convert posts into comments (which seems a bit strange to me):

- You can have just one class (e.g. Entry) with an attribute which marks it as a post or a comment, which you would set as appropriate
- You could create and save a new comment object containing the text of the post object, and then delete the post object.

Comment: I am trying to typecast objects. I defined a method for some class and some other class object also needed to access that method. I could also include it in a common helper, but i came across this and this dint work out as i thought. So wanted to know how it works.

Comment: Ok, in that case I think that for `becomes` to work Post has to inherit from Comment. As the documentation says, `becomes` is useful when you want an instance of a subclass to appear as an instance of a superclass.

Comment: Way late to the party, but as of (at least) 4.2ish, `becomes` can work between two unrelated objects.  Not advising it in any way, just stating that it does work.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that *becomes* returns a new object but does not modify the existing object. You need to do the assignment yourself

```
@post = @post.becomes(Comment)
```

See the documentation [ActiveRecord::Persistence#becomes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes)

Answer (score 5):

Put the methods you want both models to use on a module. Then include that module in both models.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is correct. Accepting the above answer as I got some accurate explanation to use becomes. :). Apologies for the delay!